# Select dynamic value with tooltip on line chart (highcharts) in angular with material slider

Tags: angular, highcharts

I need to show the selected value from slider as well as tooltip dynamically on the chart, for some reason, the mouse tracking disables the selected value and doesn't show the currently selected value from slider.

Expected behaviour: there should always be a point marker based on selected value in slider, currently it removes selected marker on mouseover.

```ts
  onSliderValueChange(v: number): void {
    this.selectedValue = v;
    for (let dat of this.chartData) {
      if (v === dat[0]) {
        const idx = this.chartData.indexOf(dat);
        const point = this.chart.series[0].data[idx];
        point.setState('select');
        point.onMouseOver();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Please refer to the code in the following link:

https://stackblitz.com/github/gsync/line-chart-with-ng-material-slider

Comment: Could you please once more describe your issue, because from my perspective everything works as expected? How would you like to show them?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use plotline, kind of a hacky solution but it works to show currently selected value

```
onSliderValueChange(v: number): void {
this.selectedValue = v;
for (let dat of this.chartData) {
  if (v === dat[0]) {
    const idx = this.chartData.indexOf(dat);
    const point = this.chart.series[0].points[idx];
    if (this.chart.series[0].xAxis['plotLinesAndBands'].length) {
        this.chart.series[0].xAxis.removePlotLine('plotline');
    }
    this.chart.series[0].xAxis.addPlotLine({
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
      width: 1.5,
      value: v,
      id: 'plotline',
    });
    point.onMouseOver();
    break;
  }
}
```

}